# Clojure: 'folding' a sequence (partitioning, as it turned out)

Tags: clojure

What is the right way of turning a flat list like this:

```
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

into a sequence of vectors:

```
([1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
```

Sorry, I suppose this is something right out of the toolbox, but I can't think of the right keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(->> '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) (partition 3) (map vec))
```

Take the original list and then partition it by 3 and finally map each partition to a vector.

I think using the `->>` macro makes it read nicer.

Answer (score 2):

```
user> (def flat-seq (range 1 10))
#'user/flat-seq
user> (map vec (partition-all 3 flat-seq))
;=> ([1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
```

Comment: That is partitioning, then. Thanks!